# Unexpected output in testing some basic javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am learning about different array functions in Javascript and I am not able to comprehend the output of a basic code that I wrote to test array.map().

```
let contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Jim",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Laura",
  "lastName": "Bush"
}, {
  "firstName": "Adam",
  "lastName": "Shaw"
}];

let tempJson = {};

const newContacts = contacts.map(contact => {
//tempJson = {}
tempJson[contact.firstName] = contact.lastName
console.log(tempJson);
return tempJson;
});

console.log(newContacts);
```

Expected output

```
//tempJson
{ "Jim": "Smith" }
{ "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush" }
{ "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush", "Adam": "Shaw" }

//newContacts
[ { "Jim": "Smith", }, 
  { "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush"}, 
  { "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush", "Adam": "Shaw" } ]
```

Actual output

```
//tempJson
{ "Jim": "Smith" }
{ "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush" }
{ "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush", "Adam": "Shaw" }

//newContacts
[ { "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush", "Adam": "Shaw" }, 
  { "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush", "Adam": "Shaw" }, 
  { "Jim": "Smith", "Laura": "Bush", "Adam": "Shaw" } ]
```

Shouldn't the new contacts array only consist of the object returned by map function?

I am missing something and I am not sure what it is.

Comment: You declared `tempJson` *outside* the `.map()` callback; it should be declared *inside*.  As it is, the same object is being added to the `newContacts` array every time.

Comment: That said, it still won't do what your "expected output" predicts. You'll end up with an array of three objects, each of which has a property name derived from a first name and a value that's the corresponding last name.

Comment: I think the basic problem is that `.map()` is the wrong function for the job; you really want `.reduce()` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the reference to `tempJson` because of which your final results in `tempJson` are reflected `newContacts`, instead `clone` your `tempJson` and then return the cloned Object.

```js
let contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Jim",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Laura",
    "lastName": "Bush"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Adam",
    "lastName": "Shaw"
  }];
  
  let tempJson = {};
  
  const newContacts = contacts.map(contact => {
    let clonedObj = {};
    tempJson[contact.firstName] = contact.lastName
    Object.assign(clonedObj, tempJson);
    return clonedObj;
  });
  
  console.log(newContacts);
```

PS: `reduce` is more appropriate as pointed by others.

```js
let contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Jim",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Laura",
    "lastName": "Bush"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Adam",
    "lastName": "Shaw"
  }];
  

const output = contacts.reduce((accu, {firstName, lastName}, i) => {
    accu.push({...accu[i-1], [firstName]: lastName });
    return accu;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.map()` function is intended to be used to take an array and transform each element into a corresponding element value for a new array. It seems that what you want to do is build up a new *object* from the elements of an array, so that's not really a job for `.map()`. The more general `.reduce()` function would be better: it allows you to accumulate results into any sort of value as iteration proceeds through the elements of an array.

In this case, you could use `.reduce()` as follows:

```
const newContacts = contacts.reduce(function(result, contact) {
  result[contact.firstName] = contact.lastName;
  return result;
}, {});
```

That second argument `{}` to `.reduce()` is the starting value. It's passed as the first argument to the callback function on each iteration, and the callback is responsible for returning the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` instead:

```js
let contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Jim",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Laura",
  "lastName": "Bush"
}, {
  "firstName": "Adam",
  "lastName": "Shaw"
}];

const newContacts = Object.entries(contacts.reduce((acc, { firstName, lastName }) => {
  acc[firstName] = lastName;
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));

console.log(newContacts);
```